# Yammer API result mismatch with page view result

Tags: api, rest, yammer

I tried Yammer REST API at https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/messages/my_feed.json for my_feed, algo and following.

According to the documentation these API results should be corresponding to the current user's All, Top and the following feeds in the Yammer view page.

However, it seems the REST API will always return the same messages as in following for both my_feed and algo, which does not match the messages I saw in my "All" and "Top" view.

Am I missing something or this is an API bug?